# Moving queue items up or down

Tags: c#

In my c sharp program, i have 5 items in queue.From 0 1 2 4.
When user press button i want to change the position of item just like
first item should be 1 and last item should become 0.
That is like 1 2 3 4 0 and again 2 3 4 0 1.
How can i do like this ?

Comment: That it not a queue (queues are FIFO data structures).

Comment: What is the code you are using? What objects/controls are you using? What have you tried?

Comment: i tried to swap the queue but failed.Its only swap the value.I just want to swap the position of queue.It has fixed item.only items should change its position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What class are you using to implement your queue?

If using a List<>, you could do it like this:

```
        List<MyQueueEntry> queue = new List<MyQueueEntry>();

        // Add stuff into the queue list

        // take the head entry, remove it from the queue and add it to the tail
        MyQueueEntry head = queue.First();
        queue.RemoveAt(0);
        queue.Add(head);
```

Comment: i am using Queue<> class not list class.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement behaviour like that by using Queue. When user click button you can do action:

```
queue.Enqueue(queue.Dequeue());
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a [Circular Queue/Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) is what you want. It wraps around.

Comment: How to implement circular queue in c sharp?any reference ?